# Print Main Menu inside a block

Tags: theming, routes

Very new to Drupal--trying to understand building a dynamic navigation menu for end users to handle. Is it possible to print the Main Menu inside a block I'm using for the header? e.g.

```
<nav id="main-menu" role="navigation" tabindex="-1">
<?php
      print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
        'links' => $main_menu,
        'attributes' => array(
          'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
        ),
        'heading' => array(
          'text' => t('Main menu'),
          'level' => 'h2',
          'class' => array('element-invisible'),
        ),
      )); ?>
</nav>
```

Pages render the `<nav>` tag, but nothing inside such as the content (basic pages) that Main Menu definitely contains so far as I can see in `/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu`.

I'm using my own sub-theme (derived from Zen, but most regions removed,) so I've been trying the code above (and variations) in a block added to the Header region. Is this not the Drupal convention?

Answer (score 0):

In a custom zen sub-theme I currently use the following code:

```
$menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
print theme('links__main-menu', array('links' => $menu, 'attributes' => array('class'=> 'menu')));
```

This is appliable to any manu – just change the name accordingly. And it's easiely printable wherever I need it (page.tpl.php). It prints a `ul´ like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-966 first"><a href="http://...">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-959"><a href="…">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-967 last"><a href="http://.…">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the [menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, which lets you easily configure as many different menu blocks as you like.

It gives many options in regards to which menu to use for a block and which levels of that menu to display.